Data Output from PostgreSQL query made in pgAdmin stacked vertically
This is what I get as result for a simple query
SELECT * FROM public.normative_documents
ORDER BY id ASC 

I don't know why is it stacked like this, as it a clean Docker image.

I tried to query from the terminal and it shows the result normally, as expected.
Rebuilding the Docker container doesn't help.

I have the same issue pgadmin4 version 8.12, I tried to set Results grid from Preferences -> Query Tool -> Results grid -> Columns sized by, but it still looks like the stacked view you shared.
It is a common issue https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/7963
Rolling back to 8.10 seems to solve the issue.
pgadmin 8.10 dpage/pgadmin4

You must be using a very old browser version. pgAdmin removed support for old browser versions. Check my comment here - https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/7963#issuecomment-2370453135
